# What Array method should I use to distribute this data into my code?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
"seeFeed": [
  {
    "photos": [
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/2-1665456270486-282C1DE0-FE05-4CA8-8285-BAC1E5E816A5.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/2-1665456271067-0DA5B656-55EC-420C-904B-543C9DA8B1FF.jpeg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "photos": [
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/1-1665454791419-5A756579-9191-49D0-8B02-89B0A232FAA4_1_102_o.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/1-1665454791945-54DF4C9A-A7E3-4ABE-BC22-6E4C3C73236E.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/1-1665454792356-282C1DE0-FE05-4CA8-8285-BAC1E5E816A5.jpeg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i received data from server like this;

However, since I don't know much about Array Method, I don't know which method to use.

```
<Slide>
<PhotoFile src={seeFeed.#$@#%@#}/>
</Slide>


<Slide>
<PhotoFile src={"https://instagram-uploadss..."} />
<Photofile src={"https://instagram-uploadsss... />
</Slide>
<Slide>
<PhotoFile src={"https://instagram-uploadsss.s...}/>
<PhotoFile src={"https://instagram-uploadsss.s..."}/>
<PhotoFile src={"https://instagram-uploadsss.s..."}/>
</Slide>
```

How do I get data and distribute it to `<Slide><PhotoFile src={}/></Slide>`?

Comment: Which Frontend  Framework are you using?

Comment: i user react.js for frontend!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using `React.js`

This can use two [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) method to achive this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
     function App () {
       
                 const seeFeed = [
  {
    "photos": [
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/2-1665456270486-282C1DE0-FE05-4CA8-8285-BAC1E5E816A5.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/2-1665456271067-0DA5B656-55EC-420C-904B-543C9DA8B1FF.jpeg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "photos": [
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/1-1665454791419-5A756579-9191-49D0-8B02-89B0A232FAA4_1_102_o.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/1-1665454791945-54DF4C9A-A7E3-4ABE-BC22-6E4C3C73236E.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/1-1665454792356-282C1DE0-FE05-4CA8-8285-BAC1E5E816A5.jpeg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
     
       
       return <div>
         {
            seeFeed.map((item)=>{
             if(item && item.photos && item.photos.length > 0){
               return <Slide> { item.photos.map((fileObj)=>{ 
                 if(fileObj && fileObj.file){
                   return <PhotoFile src={fileObj.file}></PhotoFile>
                 }
               }) } </Slide>
             }
           })
         }
       </div>
     }
     
     function Slide ({ children }){
       return <div>{children}</div>
     }
     
     function PhotoFile ({ src }){
       return <img src={src}></img>
     }
    </script>

    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(
            <App></App>
            , document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
```

Or use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to clean and get a simple **2D array** with only src string, and use `map()` again.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
     function App () {
       
                 const seeFeed = [
  {
    "photos": [
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/2-1665456270486-282C1DE0-FE05-4CA8-8285-BAC1E5E816A5.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/2-1665456271067-0DA5B656-55EC-420C-904B-543C9DA8B1FF.jpeg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "photos": [
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/1-1665454791419-5A756579-9191-49D0-8B02-89B0A232FAA4_1_102_o.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/1-1665454791945-54DF4C9A-A7E3-4ABE-BC22-6E4C3C73236E.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "file": "https://instagram-uploadsss.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/1-1665454792356-282C1DE0-FE05-4CA8-8285-BAC1E5E816A5.jpeg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
     
       
       return <div>
         {
            seeFeed.reduce((prev, curr) =>{
              if (curr) {
                prev.push(curr.photos.map((file)=> file.file));
                return prev;
              }
            }, []).map((item)=> <Slide>{item.map((src)=> <img src={src}></img>)}</Slide>)
         }
       </div>
     }
     
     function Slide ({ children }){
       return <div>{children}</div>
     }
     
     function PhotoFile ({ src }){
       return <img src={src}></img>
     }
    </script>

    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(
            <App></App>
            , document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
```